# Cypress Add multiple function/event on plugins/index.js on file preprocessor

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I add multiple events on file:preprocessor?
I'm struggling to have the webpack plugin and cypress-select-tests plugin on file:prep

I tried below but it will just process the last one.

```
const cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor = require('./cy-ts-preprocessor');
const selectTestsWithGrep = require('cypress-select-tests/grep')
module.exports = (on, config) => {

on('file:preprocessor', cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor);
on('file:preprocessor', selectTestsWithGrep(config));
```

Also, did like below and still to no avail.

```
const cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor = require('./cy-ts-preprocessor');
const selectTestsWithGrep = require('cypress-select-tests/grep')
module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('file:preprocessor', { cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor, , selectTestsWithGrep(config)});
```

Any inputs are much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting when you're using this `module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor);
    on('file:preprocessor', selectTestsWithGrep(config));
}`

Comment: @AlapanDas I'm getting this error: ``` Cypress throwing SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (17:0) ``` since the webpack preprocessor was overriden by cypress-select-tests plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cypress v4.4 or greater, you don't need `cy-ts-preprocessor`,
see [TypeScript
Support](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#History)

**History**

| Version | Changes |
| --- | --- |
| 5.0.0 | Raised minimum required TypeScript version from 2.9+ to 3.4+ |
| 4.4.0 | ***Added support for TypeScript without needing your own transpilation through preprocessors*** |